# Problema com em mostrar a BufferedImage no JPanel do Java

Tags: java, swing

Estou aprendendo Java e estava precisando usar BufferedImage, mas por algum motivo este parece não funcionar

O Erro é que o desenho não aparece no painel, segui vários tutorias mas ainda sim não da certo, não sei qual pode ser o problema

Usei o BorderFactory para ver se o painel estava funcionando, e sim o painel esta correto, porém o desenho dentro do painel não aparece

Alguém consegue descobrir o porque não aparece o desenho? Era para aparecer um quadrado na tela

```java
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class App extends JFrame{



        public App() {
            super("Buffered Test");
            add(new Pane());
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
            setVisible(true);       
        }



        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    new App();
                }   
            });
        }

    }


//Classe do painel
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Pane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;
        private Graphics2D g2d;

        public Pane() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

            img = new BufferedImage(App.WIDTH, App.HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            g2d = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();


            draw();
        }


        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }

        public void draw() { //Metodo para fazer o desenho
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }
```

[image: Este é o resultado do código, a borda aparece, então o painel esta funcionando]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você precisa mudar é o método `paintComponent`, você não está sobreescrevendo o método da superclasse devido o parâmetro estar errado, o correto é `Graphics`, não `Graphics2D`.

Em segundo lugar, `App.WIDTH` está retornando `1` e `App.HEIGHT` está retornando `2`. Mesmo com o método acima corrigido, a imagem será desenhada com largura de 1 e altura de 2 pixels. Como você colocou a borda, nem assim a imagem apareceria. Mude esses dois parâmetros do construtor para o tamanho correto.

Apague seu método `draw()`. Se sua intenção era de mudar a cor da imagem apenas definindo a cor preta no `Graphics2D`, não é bem assim que se faz. Na verdade, na sua implementação, seria desenhado um retângulo preto na `BufferedImage`, mas como ela já estaria preta, também não daria pra notar.

No lugar do seu `draw()` coloque `repaint()`. Este é o método do `JPanel` que chama a pintura na tela, em outras palavras, ele chama o `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Por isso você deve ter em mente que, seja o que for que você quer ter como resultado visual, precisa estar implementado em `paintComponent`.

Se você está começando agora no Java, não recomendo `Swing` logo de cara.

Comment: Valeu, arrumei aqui e deu certo, agr eu entendi como funciona, valeu mesmo